# Why is implicit expansion not always faster on GPU?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to subtract two matrices of "different" sizes in Matlab on my GPU.

```
a = randn(87,1,10,'single','gpuArray');
b = randn(87,100000,1,'single','gpuArray');

dev = gpuDevice;
tic
out1 = a-b;
wait(dev)
toc

tic
a = repmat(a,[1 size(b,2) 1]);
b = repmat(b,[1 1 size(a,3)]);
out2 = a-b;
wait(dev)
toc
```

As you can see, there is implicit expansion along the second and third dimensions. Typically, implicit expansion is much faster than replicating matrices. However, in this case it gives the result:

```
Elapsed time is 0.033324 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.018052 seconds.
```

This is perplexing because replicating matrices is much faster than just letting implicit expansion handle the difference. I tested this on the CPU and got:

```
Elapsed time is 0.078726 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.356435 seconds.
```

What exactly is going on here? Why is implicit expansion so much slower?

I tested this on Matlab 2018b and 2019a prerelease and got this result on both.

Edit: Due to popular demand I used the timeit and gputimeit functions on both and this just reaffirmed my results

```
clear
close all
a = randn(87,1,10,'single','gpuArray');
b = randn(87,100000,1,'single','gpuArray');

dev = gpuDevice;
disp(gputimeit(@() a-b))

disp(gputimeit(@() a>b))

t1 = gputimeit(@() repmat(a,[1 size(b,2) 1]))+gputimeit(@() repmat(b,[1 1 size(a,3)]));
a = repmat(a,[1 size(b,2) 1]);
b = repmat(b,[1 1 size(a,3)]);

disp(t1+gputimeit(@() a-b))

disp(gputimeit(@() a>b))

clear
close all
a = randn(87,1,10,'single');
b = randn(87,100000,1,'single');

disp(timeit(@() a-b))

disp(timeit(@() a>b))

t1 = timeit(@() repmat(a,[1 size(b,2) 1]))+timeit(@() repmat(b,[1 1 size(a,3)]));
a = repmat(a,[1 size(b,2) 1]);
b = repmat(b,[1 1 size(a,3)]);

disp(t1+timeit(@() a-b))

disp(timeit(@() a>b))
```

And the times are:

```
    0.0249880485773384

    0.0191386963821538

    0.0159509649972431

   0.00518230250048866

    0.0980248506300088

    0.0545817410501994

     0.283484452903233

    0.0540456719899175
```

Comment: @SardarUsama Prerelease

Comment: `tic`/`too` is not a good way to time things. There is overhead in loading functions for the first time, and things that are fast will have a large uncertainty in timing. You are better off putting the code to be timed in a function, then using `timeit` to measure how long it takes to run that function.

Comment: Just in continuation of @Cris's comment, the corresponding command for timing things on GPUs is `gputimeit` https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/gputimeit.html

Comment: @NickyMattsson I did that and it doesn't make a difference. That's what the `wait(dev)` statements are for, they're exactly what `gputimeit` does

Comment: `tic`, `toc` with `wait(dev)` is not the same as `gputimeit`. `tic` `toc` is a simple stopwatch, `timeit` and `gputimeit` may run the code several times and finds the median of the run-times. But there is, of course, a lot of cases, where the simple stopwatch is representative and they will give the same answer.

Comment: As for your question, I believe the reason is that when you use implicit expansion or `bsxfun` for that matter, Matlab tries to balance performance and memory usage. If you use `repmat` you do not balance anything. Thus for CPUs where you only have to feed a few number of cores through a small cache the continuous expansion is fast enough to keep up with the cache. For GPUs you have a lot of cores, so here you benefit from expanding immediately, so you can feed all the cores. That is at least my understanding.

Comment: @NickyMattsson Thanks, that makes sense. I did utilize `bsxfun` instead of just `-` and it did allow me to gain a speedup but not quite to the effect that I would expect.